# Twitter deep link android does not work

Tags: android, twitter, android-twitter

Please help me this problem.
Currently I want to open my app when user click on my post (click on a link) in Twitter. 
I am following the instruction here : https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile But it does not work.

I tested with a simple html file with those of header's metadata:

```
<head>

<meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="AndroidApp">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.example.androidapp">
<meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="twittersharing://action">

</head>
```

And here is the intent filter in my app :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <data android:scheme="twittersharing" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I have tested with this command : adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "twittersharing://action". I can launch my activity.

I research and figure out that there was some problems about Twitter deep link before. For example here :
[Android deep linking - passing data through scheme not working](https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-deep-linking-passing-data-through-scheme-not-working/16104/6)
I think they had fixed..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd love to know how you did.

Comment: So sorry @Fitterman. I could not make it run... and finally removed that feature.

Comment: Did you find anything related this post ?